# Get mime type of image from storage?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm getting a file from storage using:

```
$image = Storage::get('test.jpg');
```

How can I get it's mime type?

I've tried:

```
$mime = Storage::mimeType($image);
```

With no luck.

I need the mime type so I can return the image as a response:

```
$response = Response::make($image, 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', $mime);
return $response;
```

Comment: You wont to download image?

Comment: I do not want to download the image - I want to return an image as a response.

Answer (score 25):

When using the Storage facade in a controller, you can return the image as a response in Laravel 5.7. The response() function will automatically set the headers required rather than attempting to do it yourself.

```
// Option #1
return Storage::response('test.jpg'); // Local storage
// Option #2
return Storage::disk('s3')->response('test.jpg'); // If you are using an S3 driver
// Option #3
return Storage::cloud()->response('test.jpg'); // Also S3 driver unless otherwise configured
```

This is not documented, but can be found by looking at the underlying Laravel code:

[`/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemAdapter.php#L128)

If you still need to get the mime type for any reason, you should be able to retrieve it by calling:

```
$mimeType = Storage::mimeType('test.jpg');
```

Comment: This does not seem to be available "out of the box". Maybe this has changed since 5.7? In 10.0, `Storage::disc()` returns `\Illuminate\Contracts\Filesystem\Filesystem` which does not have a `response()` method without customizing the filesystem (which is not as straightforward as one would prefer, at least looking at their docs alone): https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#custom-filesystems

Comment: If you want to get the file mimetype for a file on a specific disk use: `Storage::disk('s3_or_any_other_disk_name')->mimeType($filePath);`